# CorePlot black edge

Tags: ios, xcode, core-plot

How do I avoid this annoying black edge? (I already set all `UIView's.backgroundColor's` to `[UIColor clearColor]`)!

[image: Pic]

Comment: Is the offending corner on the hosting view or part of the graph? If so, which part?

Comment: I saw that it maybe is the .layer.borderWidth property. I will try that. What views / layers are changed by an template in CorePlot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is it:

```
graph.plotAreaFrame.borderLineStyle = nil;
```